# How to execute a script tag inside a script returned by jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

One of my clients would like to execute a script after the rest of the page content has fully loaded.

I suggested the following jquery function:

```
script>

$(window).load(function() {
$.getScript("http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/JavaScriptTest");
});

</script>
```

Which calls the script above only after the rest of the page has loaded. However, the script above is also supposed to call another script after it executes. This looks something like the below:

```
function AT_tags(){
  try{var tags = new Array();
    var imgs = new Array();
    tags = [];
    for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++)
    { imgs[i] = new Image();
      imgs[i].src = tags[i];}
    this.csk='Test';
  }catch(e){this.csk='Error';}}
var AT_csk = new AT_tags();
document.write('<s'+'cript language="JavaScript" src="http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/KamuiTag/"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

The second script - that says jaction/KamuiTag - isn't executing when the first script is called this way.

Can someone please explain to me why a script within a script that executes using the above jquery function would not get called?

Also, does anyone have any fixes or suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Where was AT_tags used?

Comment: Ahhh atlas tagging.
Are you sure that the atlas object isn't available on the page?

Comment: document.write after the dom is ready is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the DOM.

```
document.head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
js.setAttribute('src','http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/KamuiTag/');
document.head.appendChild(js);
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the client would like the script to execute strictly after page load, and when I tried this it loaded at the same time the rest of the content on the page did.

Comment: Well you wouldn't just paste this directly in scope for execution, you'd like to wrap it in a function and call the function at the point of desired execution.  I haven't battle tested that, by any means, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback for `$.getScript()` like below;

```
<script>

$(window).load(function() {
  $.getScript("http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/JavaScriptTest", function() {
    function AT_tags(){
      try{var tags = new Array();
        var imgs = new Array();
        tags = [];
        for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++)
        { imgs[i] = new Image();
          imgs[i].src = tags[i];}
        this.csk='Test';
      }catch(e){this.csk='Error';}}
      var AT_csk = new AT_tags();
      $.getScript("http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/KamuiTag/");
  });
});

</script>
```